# QT Network Access Manager retrievs empty JSON file

Tags: c++, json, qt

This following code retrieves a JSON file from a [NGROK](https://ngrok.com) url, which leads to the directory listing of the game files, where the JSON file is stored:

```
//header file
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QFile>
#include "board.h"

class Client : public QObject
{
    public:
        void startRequest();
        void processRequest();
    private:
        Board b;
        QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
};

#endif // CLIENT_H
```

```
//cpp file
#include "client.h"
#include "board.h"

//go to the NGROK url and retrieve the json file containing the game data
void Client::startRequest()
{
    QUrl json = QUrl::fromUserInput("URL goes here");
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(json);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");

    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &Client::processRequest);
}

//retrieve the data from the json file
void Client::processRequest()
{
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QJsonObject data;
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(request, QJsonDocument(data).toJson());

    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QByteArray response = reply->readAll();
        qDebug() << response;
        QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response);        
        QJsonObject data = doc.object();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "File failed to load --" << reply->errorString();
        manager->clearAccessCache();
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

It executes successfully, but qDebug() returns an empty byte array, resulting in the QJSON document and objects being empty as well. What could be causing this?

Comment: Which part of `processRequest` sets its `request`'s URL, where the HTTP POST request goes?

Comment: Proxy the request to see what is being received: `socat  -v TCP-LISTEN:666,forever,reuseaddr,fork TCP:example.com` or `socat  -v TCP-LISTEN:666,forever,reuseaddr,fork TCP:192.168.0.114:4040`

Comment: Why do you call post() with an empty request in your processRequest() function? Any why do you expect that this request immeditelly contains some data?